# Check whether app got exited or not in XCUITests

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am writing a test case where i wanted to know whether the app is getting exited or not,

```
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.launch()
    ...             // After few statements
    if app.exists {
        print("App exists")
    }
    else{
        print("App got killed")
    }
```

Prior to conditional statement the app gets killed, so app.exists is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might solve your problem

```
func appExists() -> Bool{
    return appDriver!.accessibilityActivate()
}
```